# libtool - ld: framework not found AdSupport

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, libtool-xcode

I'm trying to convert FirebaseAnalytics (and later the other Firebase Frameworks) to a dynamic framework. I am following the instructions mentioned [here (method 1)](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/convert_static_to_dynamic.html).

when trying to execute the following command

```
libtool -dynamic *.o -o libfoo_dynamic-x86_64.dylib -framework CoreFoundation -lSystem
```

I'm getting

```
ld: framework not found AdSupport for architecture x86_64
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? I tried adding

```
-framework AdSupport
```

resulting in

```
ld: framework not found AdSupport
```

Probably I would just need to tell libtool where to find the AdSupport framework. But I did not find an explanation on how to do this.

Comment: Just a question: is AdSupport supporting the architecture x86_64 - isnt AdSupport an iOS Library, thus only supporting armv7, armv7s, arm64 And the tvOS ones? I might be wrong, tho. https://developer.apple.com/reference/adsupport

Comment: Might be! So I tried doing the same for arm64 - same result

Comment: Can you provide your .c-File? In their example they globally import CoreFoundation, did you try this as well for your file with AdSupport? 
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't support the .c file as I only have .o files... As said, I'm trying to convert the FirebaseAnalytics static framework from static to dynamic - without having the code though...

Comment: Have you tried to use the approach provided by Xcode 6.1 supported for iOS8 and newer versions? New Project -> iOS -> Framework & Library -> Cocoa Touch Framework Here you can build the dynamic library. And I think you can also manually add the required references ?

Comment: I did! But this results in a linker error saying `4 Duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64`